# How to replace '-' with '.' in a string, excluding the time?

Tags: regex, string, date, replace

I am trying to replace hyphens (-) with periods (.) in a string that contains both date and time information. For example, I want to change "2022-10-20 02:47:29" to "2022.10.20 02:47:29," while keeping the time part unchanged.

In a previous question, I attempted to use replaceAll('-', '.') and substring operations, but it didn't provide the desired result. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code I tried:

```
const originalString = "2022-10-20 02:47:29";
const modifiedString = originalString.replaceAll('-', '.'); // It seems like this part is incorrect.
console.log(modifiedString);
```

The code above changes the entire string, including the time part, to dots. How can I modify only a specific portion of the string?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you need regex? Just use replaceAll and substring `"2022-10-20 02:47:29".replaceAll('-','.').substring(0,10)`

Comment: `replaceAll()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split` with a space to get first part which is `date` and then use `replaceAll` to replace all dashes `-` with dots `.`.

```js
const str = '2022-10-20 02:47:29'

const [date, time] = str.split(' ')

// const [date] = str.match(/\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}/);  // with regex

const result = date.replaceAll('-', '.');

console.log(result)
```